# Open url in a new window using javascript

Tags: javascript, window.location

I have tried `target="_blank"` and other ways so that below window opens in a new page instead of replacing the current page but its not working.

Can someone would be able to help me get this fixed?

This is the code I am using:

```
$("#yes").click(function() {
  answer();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.cookie("answered", "yes", {path:"/", expires:730});
    window.location = "http://www.google.com", "_blank"
  }, 2E3)
});
```

Comment: `$("#yes").click(function(){answer();setTimeout(function(){$.cookie("answered","yes",
{path:"/",expires:730});window.open("http://www.google.com")},2E3)});`

Answer (score 3):

[`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open):

> Loads a resource into either a new browsing context (such as a window) or one that already exists, depending on the specified parameters.
>
> syntax:
>
> ```
> var windowObjectReference = window.open(strUrl, strWindowName[, strWindowFeatures]);
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `window.open` instead:

```
window.open('url', 'name', 'window settings')
```

Check this **[Online Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open)** and **[window open documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)**

> **`name`** is optional. Specifies the target attribute or the name of the window. The following values are supported:
>
> - _blank - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default
> - _parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame
> - _self - URL replaces the current page
> - _top - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded
>
> or **`name`** - The name of the window
>
> **window settings** is optional.

Answer (score 0):

`window.open()` is a method that you can pass a URL to that you want to open in a new window. For example:

**window.open() example:**

```
window.open('http://www.google.com'); //This will open Google in a new window
```

Additional Information:

`window.open()` can be passed additional parameters. See:[window.open tutorial](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)